# Does an XPath selector can be find to accommodate multiple scenarios?

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

### Context

I'm trying to get an Xpath selection that can accommodate two scenarios. My crawler visits several pages and look for a particular table with an Xpath selector. Then, the crawler parse the table and is designed to accommodate with the first scenario which is the most common.

But in some cases, datas is presented differently, as you can see in the second scenario.

### First scenario

```html
<tr>
    <th>node_1</th>
    <td>
        <div class="plainlist">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=#>item_1</a></li>
                <li><a href=#>item_2</a></li>
                <li>item_3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The Xpath selection works well with this:

`table.xpath('//tr/th[contains(text(),"node_1")]/following-sibling::td//text()[normalize-space()]').getall()`

### 2nd scenario

```html
<tr>
    <th>
        <div>Node<br>name</div>         #subnode + formatting
    </th>
    <td>
        <div>
            <div class="plainlist">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item_1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item_2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

### Issue

Is there an Xpath selector that can accommodate both scenarios or do I need to try the first selector and write another one if no results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and `output_processor = TakeFirst()` for an item:

```
l.add_xpath('FieldName', '//your/first/xpath')
l.add_xpath('FieldName', '//your/second/xpath')
```